# Can a static variable in a static function move to a new address in memory?

Tags: c++

I just upgraded to a new version of a third party library (QtPropertyBrowser for Qt 5.0).  The upgrade led to a new bug in my application which I managed to track to a static function in the library.  The function contains a static variable that is initialized the first time the function is called.  I copied down the memory location of that variable after initialization and found, as expected, that on multiple subsequent calls that the variable remained in the same memory location.  Then on a subsequent function call I noticed that the memory location and data in the static variable had changed (causing the bug in my program).

The code looks something like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    //.... 
};

class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassA* ptrMember;
};

static ClassA *theFunction()
{
    static ClassB statVar = {0};
    if(!statVar.ptrMember)
        statVar.ptrMember = new ClassA();
    return statVar.ptrMember;
}
```

I found that during multiple calls to `theFunction()` the address stored in `&statVar` always remained the same, but then on a subsequent call the address in `&statVar` was different and `statVar.ptrMember` was empty.

I didn't think this was possible!  Any ideas?

Comment: Which of the above parts are in headers vs. cpp files?

Comment: Originally everything was templated in headers and called using complex macros.  In order to debug what was going on I reproduced the classes and function without templates or macros and put them all in the relevant .cpp file.  The issue is the same in both cases.

Comment: To clarify are you saying that the address of the static variable itself (`&statVar`) changes? Or that the pointer to `ClassA` inside it changes? The second is easily explained since you overwrite it each time the function is called; the first would be more mysterious.

Comment: You create a new `ClassA` each time you call the function. Is that intended?

Comment: I think you're calling it from *different* translation unit (TU). The function is declared `static`, which means each TU gets its own version along with the static variable. Have you defined the function in the header, and included in many `.cpp` files? Please write which part of your code goes in which file, and from which file you're calling this function.

Comment: @Mike, I have edited the question to make it more clear.  The statVar.ptrMember is actually only being set when the statVar object is initialized.

Comment: @Nawaz, that sounds like the type of answer I am looking for.  This function, which is in a third party library, is being called multiple times from a dll of ours.  It is then called by an exe that uses the dll and that is the point at which the strange behavior occurs.

Comment: A static variable **is** its address. It cannot change. You are looking at a different static variable in a different static function, thanks to the wonders of DLL technology and static libraries mashed together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've *defined* the function in a header file, and have included in many `.cpp` files (each `.cpp` file defines one translation unit).

Since the function is declared `static`, each translation unit gets its own version along with the `static` variable. That is why, the address of the static variable is different when you call the function from different translation unit. As long as you call it from same translation unit, you will see the same address.

Note that the address will remain same for a particular translation unit. It is just that each translation unit will have its own version of the static variable, hence different address; you're **not** accessing the same variable anymore, they're different variable with same identifier.

---

> The problem is that this is all defined in a third party library and I need to call it from both a dll and an exe without the static variable getting reinitialized. Is there any way that I can take care of the problem without altering the code in the library? I am currently using the library as a .lib. Would the problem go away if I compiled it as a .dll instead?

To avoid multiple version of the static function (hence static variable), you need to call it from same translation unit. To do that, you can use *proxy* to call the function. That is, instead of directly calling the function, call a proxy (which is defined in a single translation unit, no more version).

- Declare the proxy in a header:

  ```
  //proxy.h
  ClassA *proxy_of_theFunction();
  ```
- Define the proxy in an implementation file:

  ```
  //proxy.cpp
  ClassA* proxy_of_theFunction()
  {
      return theFunction(); //call the actual function
  }
  ```

Call `proxy_of_theFunction`. That should solve your problem.

Since `proxy_of_theFunction` is **not** `static` (and it is defined in `proxy.cpp`), it has only one version; no other version. Since there is only one proxy from which you call `theFunction()`, you're calling the *same* version of `theFunction` everytime, hence you will see *same* version of `static` variable for every call. :-)

Comment: The problem is that this is all defined in a third party library and I need to call it from both a dll and an exe without the static variable getting reinitialized.  Is there any way that I can take care of the problem without altering the code in the library?  I am currently using the library as a .lib.  Would the problem go away if I compiled it as a .dll instead?

Comment: @Joey: I think you can do something. Some workaround. Let me suggest one solution.

Comment: Great idea! In my case its a little more complicated, but I think I can move the class that was using the code from the exe to the dll, which is effectively what you're saying. I'm trying that now.